# Angular -Binding Error: Can't bind to 'ngIf'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-routing

I have tried to solve this issue without having success.
It's strange becuase this the module that return teh issue is the replica of another one that works fine.

I have shared the [folder on gitHub](https://github.com/leepaolo/routing-issue) - I will be happy if somebody can help me to figure how to fix it.

Thank you so much
P.

[image]

Comment: Please provide code for ts and html

Comment: <div *ngIf="card">
  <h2>{{ card.titleHeader }}</h2>
  <!-- Add other properties as needed -->
  <img class="main-image" [src]="card.image" alt="Tour Image">
  <p>{{ card.fullDescription }}</p>
  <p>English {{ card.english }}</p>
  <p>Italian {{ card.italian }}</p>
</div>

Comment: Check the repository https://github.com/leepaolo/routing-issue

Comment: you haven't shared your code and the error shown in your attached image has nothing to do with the title of this post. Please post a real question before waiting for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **? in interpolation object variable** in your HTML Tag as shown below in the code.

It is shorthand to write as **(card || {}).titleHeader**

```html
<h2>{{ card?.titleHeader }}</h2>
```